# Понять строку $conn->connect_error в условии

Tags: php

Помогите понять строчку в условии

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Ошибка подключения: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

В условии переменная $conn потом connect_error которая возвращает последнюю ошибку в подкл.
Что делает -> ?
Почему connect_error не переменная?
Что такое die?
Где найти примеры всего этого?

Comment: читатйте книгу по PHP. например "PHP 7. Дмитрий Котеров, Игорь Симдянов."

Answer (score 0):

Не стал минусовать ваш вопрос, просто поищите на Ютубе "Подключение PDO php" и посмотрите 3-4 ролика разных авторов

Разумеется вы новичок и в комментах вам никто не прочитает лекцию про методы и их вызов) Просто очевидно что вы откуда-то скопировали код и вставили себе в программу не разобравшись как и что должно быть прописано)

Учитесь, старайтесь понять как оно работает) Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо все верно. Трудно учить OOP без него материал дается легче. Неужели в начале изучения php необходимо сразу начинать с oop,?

Comment: Не расценивайте следующие слова как вектор для будущего развития в програмировании)

Я сам до сих пор не знаю толком ООП и мне не стыдно) Важно учить не вообще все и не то что модно) Важно практиковаться в том, что требует от вас ситуация) 

Например не углубляясь в ООП, вы можете научиться коннектиться с БД, можете изучить конструкцию TRY CATCH, соедениться с Базой при помощи надежного и современного способа, а весь остально код писать процедурным методом)

Comment: @KoRn во-первых для работы с mysqli предоставлены функции в процедурном стиле в том числе. во-вторых никто **в начале изучения** не начинает с БД, а начинают с более простых вещей и к тому моменту, когда дело дойдёт до БД, обычно начинает потихоньку всплывать тема шаблонов и применения классов (т.к. для работы с БД обычно применяется паттерн Одиночка...а это класс). Так что надо идти последовательно с **начала в конец**, а не с конца в начало.